# Login through Twitter app says like App not authorized to access user account

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

We have developed an app in iPad which also provides ability to login through Twitter account. We created developer account on Twitter and provided valid details like token and secret key to the code. But when try to login, it says like App is not authorized to access user account. I ensure that read/write permission is granted in Twitter app on Twitter developer account.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. The reason was, had to set Website address and Callback URL same from Application Settings on Twitter Developer account.

Comment: can you kindly provide a block of code, using whech you make a request to twitter for user information? or unswer me here: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268266/how-get-user-info-from-twitter-via-api