# How get user info from twitter via API?

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm developing API to integrate rails app with twitter.

I receive from client only:

```
{
  provider:     'twitter',
  user_id:      'USER_ID',
  access_token: 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
}
```

But I need create user and save it into database if user is not registered etc. I have models `user` and `authentication` (user has many authentications):

```
class User
  validate :first_name, :last_name, :email, 
           presense: true 

  has_many :providers
endd

class Authentication
  validate :provider, :user_id, :access_token, :refresh_token, :expires_at, 
           presense: true

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Twitter app is already created and all permissions are set up correctly.

Problem:

To save user with authentication into DB - I need to have all fields.

Question:

If I have `provider`, `user_id` and `access_token`, 
  how can I get additional fields: 
  `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `refresh_token` and `expires_at`.

Which API request should I make?

P.S. I found that with `gem "twitter"` I can get user information:

```
@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key    = "TWITTER_API_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret = "TWITTER_API_SECRET"
end
user_info = @client.user 'USER_ID'
```

It returns an object with user info, which contain `first_name` and `last_names`.
But I still don't know how to get `email`, `refresh_token` and `expires_at` fields. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... I think you're trying to create a logging for your app, is it?

There is not API request for this exactly, but you can use the `twitter` gem for this. Hope it works for you.

https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Comment: Yes, exectly. it will be social login - but via API. can you kindly provide me simple example of code with request? I am searching for some lightweight resilution. and I know that there are some difficulties with getting user email from twitter...

Comment: I'm looking for it in the Twitter API and Google. But... Nothing for Ruby. There is something for C#. In this gem there is something to connect your account, anyway.